# How can I clone and use only part of a Git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

My repo now depends on a 6GB repo If I make is a submodule it downloads the whole 6GB for all my developers. I only need a tiny bit of the repo. How can I only clone the small part of the submodule that's relevant to my repo?

I'm looking for something I can put in the .gitmodules file like:

```
[submodule "external/bigrepo"]
    path = external/bigrepo
    url = ../../BigDevs/bigrepo.git/little/piece/of/it
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No easy way. Does that contain your answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository

Comment: Does "I only need a tiny bit of the repo" mean "I only need to most recent revision, not the whole history" or "I only need a particular file / directory, not the whole revision tree"?

Comment: I only need a particular file / directory, not the whole revision tree.